# Downloading images with Mechanize gem

Tags: ruby, image, mechanize, download

I'm trying to download all full-res images from a site by checking for image links, visit them and download the full image.

I have managed to make it kinda work. I can fetch all links and download the image from `i.imgur`. However, I want to make it work with more sites and normal `imgur` albums and also without `wget` (which I am using now as shown below).

This is the code I'm currently playing around with (Don't judge, it's only testcode):

```
require 'mechanize'
require 'uri'

def get_images()
  crawler = Mechanize.new
  img_links = crawler.get("http://www.reddit.com/r/climbing/new/?count=25&after=t3_39qccc").links_with(href: %r{i.imgur})
  return img_links
end

def download_images()
  img_links = get_images()
  crawler = Mechanize.new
  clean_links = []

  img_links.each do |link|
  current_link = link.uri.to_s
  unless current_link.include?("domain")
    unless clean_links.include?(current_link)
      clean_links << current_link
    end
  end
end
p clean_links
clean_links.each do |link|
  system("wget -P ./images -A jpeg,jpg,bmp,gif,png #{link}")
  end
end

download_images()
```

Comment: You can't make code generic enough to download images from multiple sites because they'll all be different unless they're generated by the same template, unless you are content with grabbing all `img` tag's `src` attributes and grabbing advertising, bullets, and weird stuff you don't want. You'll have to do a lot of purging which will be a bigger task than you want.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. But is there a way to download images without using wget?

Comment: You're already know how to download them: `crawler.get(url)`

Comment: Yeah, but how do I save the img? :/

Comment: Look at the documentation of Mechanize::File, there's `save`, `save_as` or you can just write file.body the usual way.